# How to get auth token for PowerBI REST API?

Tags: node.js, powerbi

I am in the process of building a server-side app that is going to push the data into PowerBI's dataset. The only thing I'm struggling with is getting the bearer token to make a request to their API.

I'm getting the access token in the following way, however, I'm getting "401 Unauthorized" when using it in the request.

```
async getToken() {
    const AuthenticationContext = adal.AuthenticationContext;
    const context = new AuthenticationContext(`${ CONFIG.power_bi.authorityURI }/${ CONFIG.power_bi.tenantID }`);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(
            CONFIG.power_bi.scope,
            CONFIG.power_bi.clientID,
            CONFIG.power_bi.clientSecret,
            (error, tokenResponse) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('PowerBI Token Acquire Error:', error);
                    return reject(tokenResponse == null ? error : tokenResponse);
                }

                console.log('PowerBI Token Acquired:', tokenResponse);
                return resolve(tokenResponse);
            }
        );
    });
}

async postRowsInDatasetTable() {
    const token = await this.getToken().then(({ accessToken }) => accessToken);

    const groupId = '{groupId}';
    const datasetId = '{datasetId}';
    const tableName = '{tableName}';
   
    try {
        const result = await axios.post(
            `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${groupId}/datasets/${datasetId}/tables/${tableName}/rows`,
            {
                rows: [{
                    "status": "Deal",
                    "date": "2021-02-10T10:55:01.706Z"
                }]
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

The thing is that data push functionality is working just fine with a token which I took from PowerBI's documentation page, where they provide example API calls, as it is populated automatically based on currently logged-in user (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_postrowsingroup), which means I am simply getting the wrong token.

Could anyone please advise how to get the appropriate token, as I found nothing in the documentation?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely the service principal has no rights on the workspace in which is the dataset.

Comment: As per documentation I did set up Dataset.ReadWrite.All permission

Comment: You are following an article how to authenticate with user name and password. Dataset.ReadWrite.All is app registration permission. This is irrelevant when you are authenticating with service principal. You must add the service principal to the workspace. Read [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#get-started-with-a-service-principal).

Comment: Thanks, @AndreyNikolov. I followed all the steps in the provided doc, however, I'm still getting the same result.